# have hard time converting json string from server to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I get back json from the server, I want to make it an array and just to test it will work I do

```
JSON.parse(response.data.blocks)
```

I get this:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at contentblocks.js?KHWUmpg:87149
    at <anonymous>
```

How do I convert blocks to array so I can do this:

```
let blocks = response.data.blocks.sort(function(a,b){
    var x = a.order < b.order? -1:1
    return x
})
```

I got an error that sort did not exist, so I figured I need to make blocks an array so I can sort them.

This is what server sends back

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "blocks": {
        "0": {
            "id": 50,
            "content_id": 25,
            "type": "title-block-template",
            "content": "yeah",
            "content_type": null,
            "template_block_id": 1,
            "user_id": null,
            "meta": null,
            "created_at": "2017-08-13 17:27:53",
            "updated_at": "2017-08-13 17:27:53",
            "order": 1,
            "settings": [
                {
                    "id": 12,
                    "key": "order",
                    "value": "1",
                    "type": "integer",
                    "created_at": "2017-08-13 17:17:51",
                    "updated_at": "2017-08-13 17:17:51",
                    "pivot": {
                        "settingable_id": 50,
                        "setting_id": "12"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "1": {
            "id": 51,
            "content_id": 25,
            "type": "images-block-template",
            "content": "[]",
            "content_type": null,
            "template_block_id": 9,
            "user_id": null,
            "meta": null,
            "created_at": "2017-08-13 17:27:53",
            "updated_at": "2017-08-13 17:27:53",
            "order": 3,
            "settings": [
                {
                    "id": 19,
                    "key": "order",
                    "value": "3",
                    "type": "integer",
                    "created_at": "2017-08-13 17:26:19",
                    "updated_at": "2017-08-13 17:30:24",
                    "pivot": {
                        "settingable_id": 51,
                        "setting_id": "19"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hold your horses, if you got an error `Unexpected token o in JSON at position` - Take care of it, check your JSON, don't rush to other solutions. What happens when you try `JSON.parse(response.data)` without the `blocks`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Sorting the properties of an object

Think of it not as sorting the object, but extracting the properties (into an array) and sorting them by property name.

Let's say your original object (the one you listed out at the bottom of your question) is called `server_return_object`.

Extract the blocks into an object using

```
blocks = server_return_object.blocks;
```

Now we need the keys ("0", "1", etc) of the blocks. Extract them using `Object.keys()`.

```
block_keys = Object.keys(blocks);
```

Then we can create an array, with one element for each block. The easiest way is the `.map()` function, whose takes a list of items and performs a function on them.

```
block_array = block_keys.map( key => blocks[key] );
```

You now have in `block_array` an array of blocks, which you can then sort in any way you like. For example, to sort by the `created_at` you can use

```
block_array.sort(function(a,b){return a.created_at > b.created_at } )
```

Change the function inside the sort(), to return whatever criterion you want to sort on. If it is a simple sort on one of the properties, you can make the criterion, as shown above, a test for greater than (or less than, to sort the other way). More complex orderings are also possible, using multiple criteria.

Answer (score 1):

### It may already be parsed!

Two clues.

#### Already an object

Your display of what the server gives is already an object. It has a property "blocks" that could well be what you are after.

#### The unexpected token "o"

This is the error you get from JSON.parse when you feed an object into it, instead of a string.

Try this:

x={hello:3};
   JSON.parse(x);

Comment: can you help me figure out how to sort this object by a key? that is what I really want to do, but using sort function failed with error

Comment: This used to confuse the hell out of me when I first started in javascript. The properties of an object do not have an order. Depending on how you list them, and which version of JS you have, they may appear in different orders. Think of objects as having only equal-status properties. If you want little things inside a big collection to have an order, make the big collection an array, not an object. I've added another answer which I hope helps you.